# Date SQL query doesn't work as expected

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM incomings WHERE date >= '2011-04-01%' AND date <= '2011-04-29%'
```

And it shows results from 01-04 to 28-04. This may be a weird question but, it I think it should show results from 29-04 too, right?

What's wrong?

Comment: As far as I know, the only place where `%` can act as wildcard is the [LIKE operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) and that's a **string** comparison operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is odd. That query would normally be written:

```
SELECT * FROM incomings WHERE date >= '2011-04-01' AND date <= '2011-04-29'
```

I think from the way that you're trying to query the data that your `date` column is actually a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` column. If that's the case then `'2011-04-29%'` will be being cast to `'2011-04-29 00:00:00'`

I would recommend you use this SQL instead:

```
SELECT * FROM incomings WHERE date >= '2011-04-01' AND date < '2011-04-30'
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the purpose of the "%" here (besides making the date invalid) ?

If "date" is of type DATETIME, then :

```
'2011-04-29 00:00:00' is <= to '2011-04-29'
'2011-04-29 00:00:01' is not <= to '2011-04-29'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the leading %, the date without hours is interpreted as midnight (or the very start) of given date.

Comment: It's not leading. It's trailing.